# How to get a segmented button in ExtJS 4.1.1?

Tags: button, extjs, extjs4, radio-button

In ExtJS 5, there is a segmented button (Ext.button.Segmented). How do I get a similar functionality in ExtJS 4.1.1. I am trying to replace my radio buttons with segmented button.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has already written an extension for this - http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?132048-Ext.ux.container.ButtonSegment